# DynamoDB: Store array of IDs and do a batchGet for each ID

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

In DynamoDB, I have a `Groups` table and a `Users` table.  One or many `Users` can belong to a `Group`.

Using DynamoDB, is it possible to perform one query to get a single `Group` by ID, and also all of the `Users` in that `Group` by the `User IDs` in that `Group` record?

If not, what is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot do JOINs in NoSQL databases. The way you can do is to retrieve your group. read all the userIds. And then use either batchGet or query/scan(if its primary index) using "IN" operator